# Python: Capitalise specific words in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I am trying to write a python script to format SQL codes for better readability.

eg. converting specific lowercase words to uppercase: select -> SELECT

I am trying to do this using the reading and writing function in Python. However, I am stuck. Here is my code:

```
words = ['select', 'from', 'where']
w = open('03_TextUpper.txt', 'w')

with open('03_TextLower.txt', 'r') as file:

    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            if word in words:
                w.write( word.upper() )

    w.write( line )
```

This prints out the uppercase of the specific words, but does not remove the lowercase words.

Is there a better way of writing this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do this is two stages:

```
words = ['select', 'from', 'where']

with open('03_TextUpper.txt') as f_input:
    text = f_input.read()

with open('03_TextUpper.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for word in words:
        text = text.replace(word, word.upper())

    f_output.write(text)
```

First read the whole file into memory and make the necessary changes. Next open the file for writing and write it back.

It uses a Python string [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) to replace each word with its uppercase alternative. It does this for the whole file in one go without needing to split the file up.

---

This can be improved with the use of a regular expression to spot word boundaries:

```
import re

words = ['select', 'from', 'where']
uppercase = lambda x: x.group(1).upper()
re_replace = re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(words)))

with open('03_TextUpper.txt') as f_input:
    text = f_input.read()

with open('03_TextUpper.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(re_replace.sub(uppercase, text))
```

The regular expression is able to carry out all of the replacements in a single call.

Comment: This is great! However, this code will replace any combination of characters in the word list. For example, if words = ['select', 'from', 'where', 'in'] then words with 'in' such as obtain will become obtaIN.

Comment: Normally a regex would be used to stop that. I have updated it to use one.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening a read and write in the same instance. Try closing your read function and opening a new write function when it's done, and it could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the file once, and then write the generated list to the output file:

```
words = ['select', 'from', 'where']
data = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('03_TextLower.txt')]
new_words = [[b for b in i if b.lower() in words] for i in data]

with open('03_TextUpper.txt', 'w') as f:
   for line in new_words:
       for word in line:
          f.write("{}\n".format(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

Third party library [**`sqlparse`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse) will do this:

```
>>> sql = 'select * from foo where id in (select id from bar);'
>>> print sqlparse.format(sql, reindent=True, keyword_case='upper')
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE id IN
  (SELECT id
   FROM bar);
```